# RavenDB MaxNumberOfParallelIndexTasks not working?

Tags: indexing, parallel-processing, ravendb

Ayende, my mails are not delivered to your mailing list, so I'll ask here, maybe someone else would have a solution to my problem.

I'm testing ravendb again and again :) and I think I found a little bug. On your documentation page I read

> **Raven/MaxNumberOfParallelIndexTasks**
>   The maximum number of indexing
>   tasks allowed to run in parallel  Default: the number of processors in
>   the current machine

But beside that, looks like RavenDB is using only a one core to do indexing tasks. And it takes too long with a single core to finish indexing large dataset. I tried overriding that configuration and assigned 3 to MaxNumberOfParallelIndexTasks, but still, it uses only single core. 
take a look at this screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/Untitled.gif
CPU utilization is at 25% only, and I have a quad core processor. I didn't modify affinity mask.

Am I doing something wrong or I have just crossed a bug?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Davita,
I fixed the mailing list issue.

The problem you are seeing is likely because you are seeing only one index that has work to do. The work for a single index is always done on a single CPU. 
We spread the work of indexing across multiple CPUs on index boundary.